# Sandbox - killall Operation not permitted

Tags: objective-c, macos, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox

I'm writing a small Mac application (in Obj-C) which runs the following command:

```
system("killall Finder");
```

I wanted to see what would happen if I sandbox the app (as sandboxing will be required on June 01), and the app wouldn't work. I got the following response:

```
killall: warning: kill -TERM 6524: Operation not permitted
```

Is there any way to get around that? As in a specific entitlement to add or another way to run the command?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a lot that could be denied; the `system(3)` function, the `killall(1)` program, the introspection routines to discover `comm`->`pid` mappings, or the `signal(2)` system call that kills processes. It _looks_ like the `signal(2)` call is being denied, and I wouldn't be shocked if there's no way to send signals to processes outside the sandbox... What is your _goal_? (Surely `killall Finder` isn't the point of your application... :)

Comment: @sarnold That would be a pretty useless app :P . I'm trying to run simple commands like `defaults write com.apple.finder DesktopViewOptions -dict IconSize -integer 512`. After these, you need to `killall Terminal` for it to be put into effect.

Comment: Hrm. I think that would upset users. A lot.

Comment: Whoops... Typo... I meant `Finder`... Sorry about that. :(

Comment: @sarnold Well, I plan on warning them before the command is run...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app completely goes against the spirit of the sandbox, so there's almost no chance that the MAS reviewers will accept it. Also, you may be surprised at what "defaults write com.apple.finder" does from inside your sandbox—basically, nothing useful. You'll have to use a temporary exception entitlement to home-relative /Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist, use some non-sandbox-affected API to get the path to home (e.g., getpwent()->pw_dir), and load and save the plist directly. And then you'll discover that there is no way to call on a non-child process from a sandboxed app, period, no way around it—and if you try to system killall, it ends up running inside the same sandbox as you, and therefore has the same limitations.

However, you asked a specific question as to whether there's a way around that system killall failing, and there are at least three (not counting holes in the sandbox which have either been plugged by 10.7.4 or will surely be plugged soon):

1. You can create a helper app that isn't sandboxed, that does the killall for you. The only two App Store-approved ways to do this are XPC and SMLoginItemSetEnabled. And you're not allowed to enable the helper without the user explicitly telling you to do so.
2. You can send Finder an Apple Event asking it to quit, instead of signaling it. The easiest way to do this is to execute the Applescript 'tell app "Finder" to quit'. At least for 10.7.3 and earlier, you'll need a temporary exception entitlement to send Apple Events to com.apple.finder. (There may be different mechanisms for future OS versions, but nobody can discuss them outside the NDA forums.)
3. You can send an Apple Event to some other process—like System Events—to kill Finder on your behalf.

And so on.

Comment: No problem. You might want to try asking this on devforums.apple.com (especially if you have a Mac Developer Program membership and can therefore) see the NDA forums, and you should also file a radar at bugreport.apple.com asking for some way to do what you're trying to do. You'll probably get shot down, but you never know… and it's always better to hear a "no" for sure from Apple than to go based on some other dev's guess.

Comment: I don't believe XPC or SMLoginItemSetEnabled will let you "create a helper app that isn't sandboxed." I don't know this for sure, but I'm fairly certain that Apple will not allow apps which bundle un-sandboxed apps. Additionally Apple typically rejects apps which contain entitlements for com.apple.finder or com.apple.systemevents.

Comment: @AriX: You can `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` a non-sandboxed app from the sandbox, at least when I tested it in 10.7. But, as you suspect, Apple will reject you for bundling a non-sandboxed app. That's the whole point of the answer: there are ways to do this, but all of them go against the spirit of the sandbox, and will very likely get you rejected from the App Store. (Some details, like the last sentence of the first paragraph, are a bit out of date, but the point remains the same.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a good reason you can still kill applications like this:
[How can I terminate my app in a helper app with sanboxing enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014192/how-can-i-terminate-my-app-in-a-helper-app-with-sanboxing-enabled)