# How can I terminate my app in a helper app with sandboxing enabled?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sandbox

I've created a helper app, which monitors iTunes and launches/terminates the main app.

The launching works perfectly.
The only problem is that I'm not allowed to terminate the main app, because of sandboxing.
I get those 3 logs:

```
12/23/12 8:45:37.522 PM appleeventsd[70]: Sandboxed application with pid 8293 attempted to lookup App:"Significator 2"/8877/0x0:0x150150 ???? sess=100011 but was denied due to sandboxing. (handleMessage()/appleEventsD.cp #2007) com.apple.coreservices.appleevents.peer.0x7fd9c2401f00.xpcq


12/23/12 8:45:37.000 PM kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(8888) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd


12/23/12 8:45:37.873 PM sandboxd[8888]: ([8293]) SignificatorHelp(8293) deny appleevent-send ch.ilijatovilo.significator-2
```

I've tried terminating it like this in the helper app:

```
NSRunningApplication *app = [[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:[self mainApplicationBundle].bundleIdentifier] objectAtIndex:0];
[app terminate];
```

Of course, I could add another observer in the main app, but I want to avoid that.

Comment: are helper apps allows to work with apps *outside* of their sandbox?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Usually, a sandboxed app can not access another application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it, I had to add a temporary entitlement exception:

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
<array>
    <string>mainAppBundleIdentifier</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Vote up, because it's a specific answer.   For what it's worth, I've found that with the helper-main app thing, you can also have the helper check to see if main is running, and terminate *itself.*  W/o the entitlement you mention, apps can start others and terminate themselves, but not terminate others.

Answer (score 1):

If you place your apps in an [Application Group](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW19) you can send a signal to the main app to terminate itself.

Comment: Ok, just one question. How do I get the Team ID which I need for the Application Group key?

Comment: Ok, found it. So I tried it with **xxxxxxxx.SignificatorGroup**, which didn't work. I added it to both **.entitlements** files.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to IPC in 10.8 is using NSXPCConnection.

See the code at [Sandboxing with NSXPCConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SandboxingAndNSXPCConnection/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: I didn't mention that the target would be 10.7. Is this compatible too?

Comment: No, NSXPCConnection is only 10.8, I'm sorry

Comment: Ok, thanks though. I'll use it with the temporary exception above.

Comment: @NSAddict: XPC is available in Lion. NSXPCConnection is a Cocoa wrapper that was added in 10.8.